# Catch URL IDs from multiple matches in regexp

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm writing a simple URL parser.
With a regexp like following

```
preg_match_all('/^test\/(\w+)\/?$/', $url, $matches);
```

I can catch all URL like

```
test/5
```

and browsing $matches array I can get the ID, which is 5. That's fine.

With a regexp like following

```
preg_match_all('/^test\/((\w+)\/?)+\/(\w+)\/?$/', $url, $matches);
```

I can catch all URL like

```
test/1/5
test/1/2/5
test/1/2/3/5
```

... and so on.
The problem is that browsing `$matches` array I can't catch all the matched IDs of the variable-length part (which is `((\w+)\/?)+)`. I mean I don't catch 1,2,3 but 3,3,3. I get the last ID repeated N-times.

What am I missing?

Comment: You'd better split on `/`.

Comment: You could `preg_match` something like `^test[\d/]+$` then explode the string on `/`s.

Comment: like @toto said, you would be better splitting at  `/` and then keeping only the element from positon 1 to `table.length - 1`

Comment: I know I can use pure PHP string functions and do some splitting. But why re-invent the wheel? I would like to build a parser based on a chain of rules, from more specific to more general. Like Laravel or Symfony routing system. That's exactly regular expressions' job, so why not to use them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this job in two steps.

First, you can check the URL format:

```
^test(?:\/\d+)+$
```

[See the demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z48UWZ/1)

Then, if the test succeeds, you can extract the IDs with this regex:

```
(?:\G|^test)\/\K\d+
```

The output array will only contain the IDs.
[See the demo](https://regex101.com/r/sOJ6kc/1)

#### Explanation

- `(?:\G|^test)` matches the end position of the previous match **or** `test` at the beginning of the string
- `\/` matches a `/`
- `\K` resets the starting point of the current match, excluding here the `/` from result
- `\d+` matches 1 or more digits

Comment: This does not seem to work for me, as it catches only one ID, not an infinite list.. (the link supplied is broken)
The other important thing is roles played by the IDs, so the first n-1 IDs are categories IDs, while the nth ID is article ID. So I guess I have to explicitly keep them separated in the rule (like my example) so that preg_matches_all serves to me the categories IDs and article ID in the right order.

Comment: @user2029958 The target website had an issue earlier. It seems back online. Can you try again? For each line, the matches are made in the order. For example, for your last line, it matches `1`, `2`, `3`, `5` **in that order**. Therefore, if I understood you well,the last ID matched (`5`) is your article ID while others are categories IDs.

Comment: Thank you. Ok, it's catching what it's supposed to catch. But it's catching too much, for example test/1,2/5. I need it to be more specific about URL form, test/{id}/{id}/{id}/{id} and nothing more.
Moreover I don't understand why the end of string ($) now it's not working anymore. It's catching anything beyond the last ID, and it's not a good thing.

Comment: @user2029958 Could you detail what is _too much_? This regex captures all IDs after `test` as you mentioned in your question. Do you want to exclude the last ID of the URL (i.e. `5` for `test/1/2/5`)?

Comment: I meant strictly well-formed URL. So test/1/2/5 is matched, but test/1,2/5 is not, and test/1/2/5aaa is not. So IDs should be strictly separated by / and nothing else. String should end with a ID and no more on its right.

Comment: @user2029958 I've updated my answer. I would do this job using 2 regex: the first to test the URL format and the second extract the IDs for those the test passed.